# Design Decision: Loading an NSArray up front vs. asking delegate for specific items

Tags: objective-c, ios, design-patterns, architecture

I have a grid which I want to populate with images. So Internally I use a UITableView.
So from my point of view I now have two options to provide my class with data:

**1: Provide all the data in the beginning**:

```
PictureViewController *picVC = [[PictureViewController alloc]initWithAlbumsAndPictures:albumsAndPicturesObject]]
// Go on and display the View Controller which has now all the data it needs
```

**2: Use a delegate which asks for Albums and pictures**

```
PictureViewController *picVC = [[PictureViewController alloc]init]
picVC.delegate = self; // PictureViewControllerDelegate

....

#pragma mark - PictureViewControllerDelegate

- (NSArray *) pictureViewControllerAllAlbums:(id)sender{
    // Return all the albums
}

- (id) pictureViewController:(id)sender photosInAlbum:(id) album{
    // Return the images for the given Album
}
```

---

From my perspective the first approach would be a little bit simpler but a little less flexible maybe.

So for a case where the user has maybe 10 to 20 albums with maybe 10 - 15 images per album would you advise to use the second approach which obviously scales better since not all data has to be loaded or is the second approach a little over-engineered for such a simple case?

Comment: If you're talking about images, then you absolutely only want to load the ones that are currently visible on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always better to load what you need as opposed to loading everything at once especially when using a `UITableView` since it is already designed for loading its contents in that manor. It may be "sufficient" to load 10-20 albums with 10-15 pictures but it could be a lot faster and when those sizes increase (if they do) then it will get slower and slower. Especially for a device like the iPhone where UI responsiveness is top priority you always want to load your data in the most flexible way possible and not to load more than is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This makes sense, but let's assume that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would require me to "ask" a service for some information and this itself would be returned via delegation. Then I can't give the information to the delegate method `CellForRow...` asking for the cell because I will only have the necessary information when the service "calls me back". ?